# PDE with a condition 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, cauchy-problem, linear-pde

Given this problem

$$
\begin{cases}
2u_x - 5u_y + 3u_z=0\\
u(0,0,z)=z+3
\end{cases}
$$

The general solution is:

$$u(x,y,z)=\Phi(-5x-2y,3y+5z)$$

Regarding $u(0,0,z)=z+3$, I saw that:

$$u(0,0,z)=\Phi(0,5z)=z+3$$

I tried to replace $5z$ expression with $3y+5z$, obtaining $$\frac{1}{5}(3y+5z)+3$$

but... how to handle the $-5x-2y$ formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because only one condition such as $\quad u(0,0,z)=z+3\quad$ is not sufficient to determine the function $\Phi$.
$$u(x,y,z)=\Phi(-5x-2y,3y+5z)\quad\text{is correct}$$
$$u(x,y,z)=\Phi(X,Y)\quad\text{where}\quad\begin{cases}X=-5x-2y\\Y=3y+5z\end{cases}$$

With condition $\quad u(0,0,z)=z+3 =\Phi(X,Y)\quad\text{where}\quad\begin{cases}X=0\\Y=5z\end{cases}$

$$\Phi(0,Y)=\frac{1}{5}Y+3$$
One cannot determine $\Phi(X,Y)$ since this function is known only for $X=0$, not for all values of $X$.

Of course, this restrict the infinite set of functions $\Phi(X,Y)$ to subsets of functions but still remaining infinite.

$\frac{1}{5}Y+3=\frac{1}{5}(3y+5z)+3=\frac{3}{5}y+z+3$

For example and not exclusively: 
$$u(x,y,z)=\frac{3}{5}y+z+3+F\left(-5x-2y \right)$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function such as $F(0)=0$.

Another example :
$$u(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{3}{5}y+z+3\right)G(-5x-2y)$$
where $G$ is an arbitrary function such as $G(0)=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I want to learn how to manipulate the formulae from a mathematical point of view, just finding the closest set of solutions. No need to find the unique one. :)